# Finding the smallest value in an array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to find the smallest value in an array list(iList). The array list contains multiple items (InventoryItem) each with their own description, cost, etc. I need to find the smallest cost, and return the item that has the smallest cost. Also, I have to use a while loop and not a for. Here is my code so far:

```
public InventoryItem itemWithLowestCost() {

  int index = 0;
  double smallest = 0;

  while (index < iList.size()) {
     if (!(smallest < iList.get(index).getCost())) {
        smallest = iList.get(index).getCost();
     }

     if (iList.get(index).getCost() == smallest) {
        return //what to put here? ;
     }  

     index++; 
  }  

}
```

Comment: okay, and does this code do what you think it should? If not, why do you think it's not doing what you think you wrote?

Comment: It isn't returning the item that has the smallest cost.

Comment: remember to analyse your problem, and then write that out. If you need the lowest number, start with a "super high number" called "low", and then check "is element X lower? then set low to X". At the end of the run, you should know the lowest number. Need the item *with* the lowest number? Clearly we also need a "lowestitem" variable now that we can set in tandem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty simple. Store the current lowest, iterate through, and if something is smaller, save that. At the end return the current smallest.

```
public InventoryItem itemWithLowestCost() {

  InventoryItem smallest = iList.get(0);

  for (int i=1;i<iList.size();i++) {
    if(iList.get(i).getCost() < smallest.getCost()) {
      smallest = iList.get(i);
    }
  }

  return smallest;
}
```

If you need to use a while loop, then just use a disguised for loop ;)

```
public InventoryItem itemWithLowestCost() {

  InventoryItem smallest = iList.get(0);

  int i = 1;
  while (i<iList.size()) {
    if(iList.get(i).getCost() < smallest.getCost()) {
      smallest = iList.get(i);
    }
    i++;
  }

  return smallest;
}
```

Comment: You'd probably want the `for` loop to start with `int i = 1`, since index 0 is already taken care of in the initialization of `smallest`.

Comment: @misberner Yup. But really it makes almost no difference timewise. Will edit.

Comment: I need to use a while loop instead of a for.

Comment: @kb94 What about that?

Comment: @kb94 Glad to help! If an answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted to show that your question is resolved.